# Debug Key used in a project of my pc is not working in another pc

Tags: android, debugging, key

I have generated the api key from the debugkeystore in my development windows pc and the map works fine here. But after another person updates his subversion project with my Google Map file and the key, the map doesnt works on his machine. Need an urgent answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you sign up for Google Maps API, you used the signature of your debug keystore, and that API key is forever tied to your debug keystore.

Your friend needs to go through the Google Map API sign up process with his debug keystore signature and modify the map XML with his Google Map API key accordingly. It may be possible, however, that you give your debug keystore to your friend, so both of you are using the same keystore, and thus able to use the same Google Map API key.

So, it's imperative that both of you be careful when making changes to the map XML layout so as to override each other's Google Map API key.

You also need another Google Map API key for the release keystore that you will use to sign your release app's APK for publish to Google Play. This key should be in the map XML layout at all times so that your final release app will work correctly with Google Map.

Comment: I have shared my API key generated from my debug keystore with my friend still it doesnt works. Can there be a unified key which anyone can use sso that the map is diaplyed in any pc.

Comment: you would need to share your debug key with him also for it to work. Otherwise you'll need him to generate his own map key

Comment: So how do all the google map apps work? In that case, each user who have downloaded the app from market does not have a debug key in his device. In short, I want to develop an app which has map and the apk should show the map in any device....

Comment: Read my last sentence in the answer, for the Google map to work on any device in release, you need to request another Google Map API key for your release signing keystore. For development purposes, you can have each developer request their own Google Map API key and use it in the map layout locally on their PC, but don't commit it to the repository. Or, force all your developers to use the same debug signing keystore.